# Sharepoint 2007 custom DispForm.aspx issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I have a custom list tracking idea submissions (think virtual suggestion box) where I am attempting to customize the DispForm.aspx so that users will not see fields that are not directly relevant to viewing the submission.

I am making a copy of the original DispForm.aspx and renaming to i_DispForm_mod.aspx and then changing the settings of the list to use this as the display form.

Problem is, once I modify the display form settings, it takes over the whole ball of wax.  I can no longer access EditForm.aspx.  Clicking on "Edit" gets you the display form.

Creating the URL to the edit page manually takes you to the display page.  Creating a new item works as normal.

For some reason, SP is deciding to redirect all requests for EditForm.aspx to the display form.  Properties for the list supporting files are set to all the appropriate pages - but SP is ignoring that in favor of serving up the display form.  WTF?

I have no idea how to fix this.  This is my second go-round with this after abandoning the first list created when I first got this behaviour.

Oh and just to add additional fun, the behaviour persists after restoring to original DispForm.aspx and resetting list supporting file properties appropriately.

Absent solutions I may have to mark DispForm.aspx as radioactive, do not touch and abandon my design as unattainable.

I cannot find anything similar being documented anywhere on the web.

Comment: Did you use SharePoint Designer to specify which forms the list should use?

Comment: yep.  I have since identified some of what is going on which only leads to a different problem.

I want different edit forms available as there are several stages in the process where different details have to be entered by different people and so I followed this:  https://padavis.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/multiple-custom-editformaspx-pages-for-a-single-sharepoint-list-problem/

However this is what leads to the problem with the Display pages - but without changing the controlmode to display, SP will only allow one editform per list ... unless there is an approach I have not found yet.